# Inserting PHP variable into mySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a booking system, in which once a user books a flight, their details are sent to a mySQL table called `OABS_customers`.

It's structure is the following:

```
Name         Type(Length)    Null     Default

name         varchar(60)     No       noname
address1     varchar(60)     No       noaddress
address2     varchar(60)     No       noaddress2
county       varchar(60)     No       nocounty
postcode     varchar(32)     No       nopostcode
customer     tinyint(4)      No       
seats        varchar(11)     No       0
number       tinyint(4)      No       0
class        varchar(11)     No       noclass
username     varchar(60)     No       nousername
```

Now, my script adds all of the details with no problem - except for one column - the `username` column. I'm using this code: `$query = "INSERT INTO OABS_customers (username) VALUES ('$user')";` (provided kindly by eggyal) to take the logged in users name (which is stored in the cookie ID_my_site and `$user = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site']` - and I have tested that and it does contain the username of the logged in user) and add it into the username table, however this doesn't seem to work, and it instead displays the default value of `nousername`.

If anyone could help amend this issue I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Did you actually mean "a row called `id`", or was it supposed to be "column"?

Comment: (Deleting my answer because it's not longer relevant to your updated question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify you login mechanism to track the user ID for the session. 
Store the ID in memory or in a cookie.

Once you can store the user id now you can save it to the DB.

Comment: Storing it in a cookie wouldn't be particularly wise... the user could change it themselves!

Comment: If you store the user id in a cookie and right away save it to the DB, it should not be a problem. Remember you need to rewrite the cookie every time someone logs in.

Comment: If you're relying on the value in that cookie to give you the user's ID at various points during their session and they modify the cookie to provide you with a false ID, then it could cause all manner of problems...

Comment: ...well, the audience of my site are a fairly low-tech group, I doubt any of them would go into their browser settings and start changing cookies, or write a script doing so. Besides, changing the cookie here doesn't benefit them in any way.

Comment: This can be easily solved by adding an additional piece of information to the cookie. While saving the ID to the DB if both pieces don't match then you know they have changed the cookie.